# how to notify client that reCaptcha is successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, recaptcha

Hello i have simple form where i have google reCaptcha v2 and when user submits form i am validating recaptcha but i also send email to user inputted email and i need to send status 200 two times here is first time where i need to send it

```
request(verifyURL, (err, res, body)=>{
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success){
            return res.status(409).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'დადასტურება ვერ ვოხერხდა'
            })
        }
      return res.status(200).send({success: true})   
})
```

so if i send status code 200 and use return statement, won't it cause

> Can't set headers after they are sent

error?
if it will how can i fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you have the email sent in the same handler, and then return one success status for when captcha *and* an email has been sent successfully?

Comment: return res.status(200).send({
                       ^

TypeError: res.status is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send multiple response for a single request. You can go with either:
1. Send the mail in the same controller, and when its done successfully, then only send the response back to client. Your response will be based on both factors ie. captcha validation and email sent response
**or** 2. if you don't wanna wait for the email process.. Just send response once your captcha is verified.. and keep the mail process execution in background. In this case you need to remove the **return** keyword or else your request will end there and mail process won't execute.

However, I'll suggest you to go with the first approach. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks it worked i just deleted res.status 200 in request block

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Coding :)